# Progress dialog in an alertDialog android

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-contextmenu

I can't show my progress dialog that I want visible after the pressing of the  button in an alert dialog.
I can show it in other point of the activity so I suppose that the problem can be the first parameter context.

```
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.add("Modifica").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("list", "modifica");
                return false;
            }});
        menu.add("Cancella").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Log.i("list", "cancella");
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ARlist.this);

             alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(titoloriga);
             alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Confermi l'eliminazione?");

             alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Si",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                     Log.i("list", "si");
                     Cancellazione cancellatore = new Cancellazione();
                     pd = ProgressDialog.show(ARlist.this, "", "Cancellazione in corso", true, false);
                     cancellatore.start();


                 }
             });
                             // set negative button: No message
             alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                     dialog.cancel();
                     Log.i("list", "no");
                 }

             });

             AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
             alertDialog.show();

                return false;
            }
        });
 }//end onCreateContextMenu
```

Comment: use getApplicationconntex

Comment: what class are you extending

Comment: @DigveshPatel Nope. We can't use `Application` context for `Dialog`s... We need a `Activity` reference...

Comment: @user3266953  first is `MenuItemClickListener` callback is invoking? debug the code and check whether that listener is called or not?

Answer (score 2):

@Gopal Gopi wrote:

> We can't use `Application` context for `Dialog`s... We need an `Activity` reference...
>
> First what is `MenuItemClickListener` callback  invoking? Debug the code and check whether that listener is called or not?

Comment: ([Question answered in the comments and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments).)